# How to make edits to a LWC LightningDatatable programmatically?

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning, lwc

is there a way to edit cells in a Salesforce LWC LightningDatatable programatically and make those changes trigger the `oncellchange` event?

I want to be able to programmatically make edits (and make them visible) in a datatable column without changing the underlying data source.

Comment: What do you mean by `programatically edit cell` ? Like running a js snipper that will change the value in the cell and then trigger the oncellchange event ?

Answer (score 0):

After a while of investigation I discovered edits can be apply using the draft values datatable property, which actually paint cells' backgrounds in yellow.